# LogSine Moments $\int_0^\sigma \theta^k \ln^{n-1-k}\big| 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\big|d\theta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, moment-generating-functions

This integral is known as the moments for the generalized log-sine integrals.  The notation I am using is similar to Lewin and what he used in the 1950's-1980's.    $$
Ls^{(k)}_n(\sigma):=-\int_0^\sigma \theta^k \ln^{n-1-k}\big| 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\big|d\theta,\quad k\geq 0,n\geq 1.
$$
Note that in each case the modulus is not needed for $0\leq \sigma \leq 2\pi$.  Thanks.  The only progress I had realized was that for $k=0$ 
$$
Ls_1(\sigma)=-\sigma,\quad Ls^{(0)}_n(\sigma)=Ls_n(\sigma),
$$
explicitly leads to
$$
Ls_2(\sigma)=Cl_2(\sigma):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\sin (n\sigma)}{n^2}
$$
which is the Clausen function.

Comment: This is your 3rd question within 20 minutes...

Comment: @Shahar Ok, and what's your point?  I was aware of how many questions I have posted. Clearly you have trouble adding, as I posted 3 questions within 16 minutes, not 20.  Do you have any mathematical input on this question??  I am well aware of how many questions you can post in 24 hours.